# invoice with many items and deposit

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, database

I am building an invoice system in which the invoice has many items. my db structure as following

| invoices |
| --- |
| id |
| service_prices |
| discount |
| final_price |
| deposit |
| rest_price_to_pay |
| total_paid |
| date |
| status (1= paid - 2= not-paid 3= deposit |

| invoice_items |
| --- |
| invoice_id |
| quantity |
| service_id |
| price |
| date |

it works fine but the problem is when I need to get a daily report of each item's income to know what income I get daily from each item, it does not work properly with deposits, because when I want to get the daily items income i foreach items from invoice_items table, so when the client does deposit for sure the income will not be the equal of each item price. so i don't know how to solve it in database

Comment: How is your code trying to fetch the report? Are you joining in the invoices and filtering on status?

Comment: foreach `invoice_item` in an `invoice` display the price (in a table) and at the end display `final_price` from `invoice`

Comment: How do you know what items the invoice are referring to? There's no reference to the items in the `invoice_items` table.

Comment: @edruid  I need to get a daily report of each item's income to know what income I get daily from each item

Comment: @M.Eriksson sorry i just forget to add the date to the post, I edited it. thanks

Comment: That table still doesn't contain any reference to any specific item. It's only quantity, price and date.

Comment: @M.Eriksson it has but working with the table in StackOverflow is the best thing with me :( now I edited everything

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify your database with a more elaborate model. I currently make detailed invoices and even with discount product by product, tax calculation and all the totals...
I use this approach: During a sale I save in a "new sale" table, a new entry, it sends me back its id. With this id in reference I register a new entry in a customer table (with id of the sale) then for each product sold I register a table with the id of the sale and the rest of the data of the sale, id of the article, unit price, quantity, possible discount. This allows me to find all the necessary data when establishing the invoice. In my opinion going through a single table is tedious, how to find the details of each product? And if the product changes price, you will still need to produce an invoice with the correct prices.

Comment: _"for each product sold I register a table"_ - Are you creating tables on the fly for each sold product? That's not a good design. You could end up with thousands (or even millions) tables in your database.

Comment: In fact I create a "new_sales" table, ok, I retrieve its id (with last_inserted_id s.q.l) then for each product of my sale, I create an entry in a table called "sold_products" and I pass it the id of the "new_sale" , like that when I compose my invoice, I will look for all the products sold in the "sold_products" table with the id of the new sale, when I have this list of products, I calculate the taxes ( I'm in France) and quantities per product, I calculate the total amount of the invoice and the total amount of taxes, do you want to see a live demonstration example?

Comment: Ok, I'm with you, don't worry, the data of "new_sale" is deleted after the sale is processed. Believe me I've been developing an online sales framework for 3 years and for 6 months I've only been doing this to release a public version, I can't explain all the logic to you but it works very well. After regarding thousands of registrations, how do you think online businesses manage their bills anyway? They have databases with thousands of entries, as many as there are invoices to be produced and reproduced on demand

Comment: _"how do you think online businesses manage their bills anyway?"_ - I know how many companies does this. My comment wasn't about thousands/millions of _entries_, it was about creating thousands/millions of _tables_ since you keep saying _"I register a **table** / I register a customer **table**"_ in your answer (which is _not_ how online businesses does it). I don't see the point of a "new_sale" table though, but since I haven't seen how you're actually using it, I can't really comment too much on that.

Comment: Ok, simple translation problem, having a "new_sale" table allows me in my case to display a visual rendering in a back-end, I need it for other specifications related to my framework which can be used as software of cash. Want to see a live example? I have an online demonstration where you can simulate purchases, you will then receive 1/ your order form and 2/ your invoice when I archive the sale, after processing the order, the scenario works perfectly, I will tell you assures. I have already been producing invoice systems for my clients for several years

Comment: I'm sure it works, but if you meant that you add entries and not dynamically keep creating tables, you should edit your answer to be way more clear about that. Because creating custom tables for each customer usually comes from poor design choices. It shouldn't be necessary. And just because something works, doesn't mean that it's done in a good way.

Comment: Nope ! I don't create a new board for every sale, but: "And just because something works doesn't mean it's done the right way" -> what do you suggest? As I tell you I have several invoicing systems in production at the moment, I think I know a minimum of what I do, my clients receive income every day with my programs and my programs send to their clients beautiful invoices, I do save my clients a lot of time, but show me a better way, I'm curious

Comment: "It is possible to write working programs with bad code/design " -> I believe that you have just given one of the possible definition of computer science ... even more so with the largesse of PHP, I have corrected it, do not hesitate to tell me if my answer remains inconsistent, I will delete it